# What are the best practices to create a secure ASP.NET app?

Tags: asp.net-core

I've read a ton of articles that we need to write applications that are secure. That it's critical to write defensively from the start and implement all best practice secure suggestions.

What I can't find is the list of suggestions. I know about SQL injection attacks. But what else?

Very specifically for an ASP.NET Core 6 + Blazor server side application that will run on Azure web services. And will access an Azure SQL Database via Entity Frameworks (so no injection attack worries).

What do I need to do, and not do, to make the app as secure as possible?

And I know this is not a great thing, but limited to a reasonable number of issues to address. Yes any hole in a system is bad, but I also don't want to spend a year becoming well enough versed on every little issue and thereby never shipping.

[Originally asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75403329/what-are-the-best-practices-to-create-a-secure-asp-net-app?noredirect=1#comment133051021_75403329) where it was suggested this site might be better.

Comment: This is impossibly broad for a Q&A site. Entire libraries of books are written on this. Are you aware of OWASP as a starting place?

Comment: @schroeder Yeah, I'm aware it's really broad. And I'm here because OWASP is also incredibly broad. My hope is someone has put together something like "Do the following 17 things and your ASP.NET Core app will be 98% secure." I know that's not getting 100%, but there's only so many hours in the day. I figure if I get most of it right, then as (if?) the app takes off, then I can invest the $$$ to have someone who knows this inside-out to get the remaining little items covered.

Comment: Those 17 things would be 17 chapters on a multi-volume book collection on secure coding...

Comment: @ThoriumBR If it's learn all that or do nothing, then most applications written will do nothing. I think there can be a short clear listing of specifics. For example, if I was asked I would tell someone how to avoid injection attacks on their SQL queries and to not log anything confidential. Is that everything? No. Is it a good start? Oh yes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad to answer

Comment: If you conclude that OWASP https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DotNet_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html is too broad, I'm not sure what a summary *that can fit in the Answer space here* would do for you.

Comment: @schroeder What if I posted a question where I listed what I was doing and asked, if I were to implement one additional item, what would be most impactful?

Comment: That's too open-ended and too opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

What you are essentially asking for is the [**OWASP Top 10**](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/). These are the 10 most important categories of vulnerabilities, which you should look for in your code base.

#### 1. Broken Access Control

This is by far the most pressing vulnerability category. Far too often, endpoints don't enfore proper authorization, or otherwise give access to resources or functionality, to which an attacker should not have access to.

Another reason that this is Nr. 1 is that this encompasses a very, very wide range of vulnerabilities, and they usually have a rather high impact if exploited.

#### 2. Cryptographic Failures

This used to be called "Sensitive Data Exposure", which was the result of what often amounted to cryptographic failures. For example, downloads of sensitive documents over HTTP instead of HTTPS, or "custom encryption schemes", which are just XOR with a static value.

#### 3. Injection Attacks

SQL Injection, XSS and all the other injection attacks are compounded into one category named "Injection Attacks". Essentially, any kind of input, which the application gives more meaning to than "user input".

While many apps used to be vulnerable to this, many frameworks now try to solve this at the vendor level and make it very hard for developers to wite unsafe code.

#### 4. Insecure Design

Insecure Design is another broad category, in which the architecture as a whole has design flaws, such as relying on "trustworthy clients". There isn't a lot of concrete things to say here, because "Secure Software Design" by itself can fill books.

#### 5. Security Misconfigurations

This encapsulates all the instances, in which security mechanisms are in place, but not configured correctly. Either they are not enabled, or configured to not actually prevent anything.

A good example would be a Content Security Policy, which is configured to allow execution of inline-scripts, thus completely defeating the point of the policy.

#### 6. Vulnerable and Outdated Components

Software is based on A LOT of components. The web server to serve it, the application server to run it, countless JavaScript libraries to pad strings, etc...

All of these can have vulnerabilities and when they are found, a new version with a fix is distributed. However, very few developers actively update their components, *especially* if the update would make the new library incompatible in one form or another.

#### 7. Identification and Authentification Failures

Essentially, any kind of vulnerability, which allows an attacker to impersonate another user. This group of vulnerabilities used to be very prevalent, but increasing standardization of Identification and Authentication code made this less prevalent.

#### 8. Software and Data Integrity Failures

A rather complex topic, relating to ensuring that the data being processed is what is expected. Otherwise, malicious side effects may occur.

For example, deserialization of untrusted data can lead to remote code execution.

#### 9. Security Logging and Monitoring Failures

Very often, applications log insufficiently, and malicious actors can go unnoticed due to lack of monitoring. While not directly a vulnerability per se, it does pose a risk to the overall security of the application.

#### 10. Server-Side Request Forgery

A small group of vulnerabilties, in which an attacker can use the vulnerable application to fetch arbitrary resources.

It's noteworthy that this is a vulnerability voted in by the community, rather than resulting purely from data.

---

You may ask, what after that? The [OWASP WSTG](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/stable/) is a testing guide for web applications, which list vulnerabilities more in-depth and hos to test for them.

Depending on the scope of your application, hiring a consultant could be a worthwhile endeavor too. However, for personal projects, that is absolute overkill.

---

**Full Disclosure:** I work for a company, which provides consulting for security matters, including web applications.